# How to apply [formControl] on dynamically created ControlValueAccessor Component

Tags: angular, angular-forms, controlvalueaccessor

1. I have a `ImageHandler` component which implements `ControlValueAccessor`.
2. `ImageHandler` should be dynamically generated in another component and views will be embedded. Inputs and output can be set without any problem. But how to apply `formControl` on that embedded view or component.

`<image-handler [formControl]='fControl'></image-handler>`

Main problem is this formControl must be applied on image-handler itself, otherwise it could have been set by passing `fControl` as input and applying in `ImageHandlerComponent`.

**Current Work around:** Creating a `WrapperComponent` for `ImageHandler` or any other component like this. These wrapper based on parameter shows particular element with form control on it.
`<image-handler *ngIf='isImagehandler' [formControl]='fControl'></image-handler> 
...`

This wrapper component can be dynamically created without any problem. But this does not seems like a real solution.